# java -cp option seems not to work in Java 14 (Preview Enabled)

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to load dependencies on a Ubuntu 20.04 Machine using the java `-cp` option.

Expected behavior:

Add GSON to the classpath, before starting, so i don't need to shade big dependencies to my Application.

I use the following Test Setup:

- a jar file in the directory /opt/api called dependtesting.jar
- a "lib" folder in the same directory
- the gson-2.8.6.jar in the lib folder.

The program itself:

```
package dev.epeu.depend;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public final class Test {

  public static void main(String[] options) {
    System.out.println("running depend test...");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson("Test in JSON representation"));
  }
}
```

I build the software using gradle and shadow-jar.

build.grade:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.0.0'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Depend Testing',
                'Implementation-Version': '1.0.0',
                'Main-Class': 'dev.epeu.depend.Test'
    }
}

allprojects {

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
        options.compilerArgs += '--enable-preview'
    }

    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

    group 'dev.epeu'
    version '1.0.0'

    sourceCompatibility = '14'
    targetCompatibility = '14'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
    }

}
```

I run the software using the following command:

`java --enable-preview -cp "lib/*:." -jar dependtesting-1.0.0-all.jar`

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder
        at dev.epeu.depend.Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

Any idea how to deal with this? I have really bad internet and I really cannot upload 20mb of files at every test.

Comment: Open the jarfile with your favorite zip utility. If gson isn't in there, your shadow configuration for gradle didn't work.

Comment: thats not what i am trying to do. pls read the Question completely

Comment: The command is `java`. The `-cp` part is an option.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne that's correct. But that's not the question.

Comment: Java 14 is out of support, you should upgrade to Java 15.

Comment: Unable to update to Java 15. Software is written in Java 14.

Comment: @JanBredow The question needs to be expressed in terminology that is mutually understood, and it wasn't.

Comment: Sorry, my english kinna sucks, i'm from germany.

Comment: Using `-jar` means `-cp` is ignored. That's always been the case and isn't new.

Comment: @JanBredow Following up, _something_ needs to load the files from GSON. Whether that's you specifying a `ClassLoader`, or specifying it via `-cp` _correctly_. So to do that, you would actually reference all of the jarfiles you want to use, and then the main class to start: `java -cp gson-2.8.6.jar;dependtesting-1.0.0-all.jar dev.epeu.depend.Test`, which is `java -cp <jar1>;<jar...> <main-class>`. Keep in mind this shouldn't be a production/live code trick, as managing across different gson versions will break